# Know any documentation for taking existing cakephp site and integrating into Croogo?

Tags: cakephp, croogo

My employer runs a website with a homebrewed CMS that it has outgrown. I would prefer to use Django, but since everything is already in PHP, and I know the Cakephp framework, I'm going to just rebuild it in Cake. I've already done the gap analysis between the current site and the Cake version and it looks doable.

However, I need the site to have a CMS and don't want to put one together myself. I'd rather not reinvent the wheel. Croogo seems like the most actively developed and positively reviewed Cake CMS, so I'm leaning in that direction.

The trouble is I can't find any detailed documentation of how Croogo handles the database relative to Cake. I understand there is a direct link between the two, but is that enough for me to just trust that I can easily take an *existing* Cake site and magically integrate that with Croogo? I have a strong feeling that it won't be that simple.

I plan on to creating a fake croogo site to try to look behind the curtain, but I'd rather not have to reverse engineer the whole thing. So, does anyway know a bit about my scenario or have a resource they can point me to?

I doubt I'm the only one who wants to migrate an existing site to Croogo.

Answer (score 0):

It really isn’t that difficult to build something in CakePHP. As long as your database is normalised, and you have your models set up correctly, you can easily “bake” something specific to your needs. User authentication with bcrypt-hashed password is easy to add, as is authentication and ACL.

I have a starting point that covers the above that I use for each CakePHP project, and can quickly build bespoke websites in CakePHP with little effort, without having to shoe-horn it into a CMS or plugin. Once you go down that road and start working around a particular CMS or plugin, you’ll find yourself quickly in the same position (outgrowing your chosen CMS/plugin’s capabilities) as opposed to building something that’s fit for purpose.

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, and I will consider it. Why I'm leaning against that is that we have a small IT department that is overstretched already. To think that we would have to document and maintain a CMS in addition to our website seems like biting off too much. Plus it will increase the project's scope more than I think we can afford. But thank you, I'll look into it.